# Minus operation on char Set/Bitstring

Tags: c, character-encoding, binary, set, bit

```
typedef unsigned char Set;    
    Set s1,s2;
s1 = 0xda; 
PRINT(s1);
printf("%d\n", s1);

s2 = -s1;
printf("%d\n", s2);
PRINT(s2);
```

// PRINT shows the binary output

What I don't understand is the reason for this output ->

11011010

218

38

00100110

How can the negotiation of s1 saved on s2 (which was obviously null) change the 218 into 38?!

Comment: Omg -,- so clear, quite embarrassing! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: you can delete your question if you wants, click on delete button

Comment: @snowleg Post your comment as an answer and accept it to complete this post.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure I'm not the only one who didn't get it on the first sight so I'll try to answer it myself.

If you do this :

> s2 = 256-s1;

or this:

> s2 = 0-s1;

instead of

> s2 = -s1;

you'll see that it's still the same result. So if you assign it the way I did in my question you've to consider the implicit calculation.